# OrientDB does not delete all vertices at once when using "DELETE VERTEX ..." SQL Statement

Tags: orientdb

I created a vertex of type Message in VehicleHistoryGraph database and loaded 50,000 vertices of this type to it.

When I tried to delete all the vertices at once using this SQL statement -

```
DELETE VERTEX MESSAGE
```

I received unexpected errors saying that some of the vertices had already been deleted (but I, on the other hand, did not delete any vertices after loading) and the vertices would not delete all at once as expected (see below).

```
orientdb> connect remote:localhost/databases/VehicleHistoryGraph admin admin

 Connecting to database [remote:localhost/databases/VehicleHistoryGraph] with user 'admin'...OK
orientdb {db=VehicleHistoryGraph}> DELETE VERTEX MESSAGE

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.select from Message

Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The elements #26:38028 has already been deleted

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ORecordNotFoundException: The record with id '#26:38028' not found

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ORecordNotFoundException: The record with id '#26:38028' not found

orientdb {db=VehicleHistoryGraph}> SELECT COUNT(@rid) FROM Message

----+------+-----
#   |@CLASS|COUNT
----+------+-----
0   |null  |13546
----+------+-----

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 1.538 sec(s).
orientdb {db=VehicleHistoryGraph}> DELETE VERTEX MESSAGE

Delete record(s) '11896' in 107.861000 sec(s).

orientdb {db=VehicleHistoryGraph}> SELECT COUNT(@rid) FROM Message

----+------+-----
#   |@CLASS|COUNT
----+------+-----
0   |null  |1820
----+------+-----

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.167 sec(s).

orientdb {db=VehicleHistoryGraph}> DELETE VERTEX MESSAGE

Delete record(s) '1820' in 6.320000 sec(s).

orientdb {db=VehicleHistoryGraph}>
```

**What went wrong? why? Is it a bug?**

Comment: Seems your graph is broken: probably you deleted some edges manually?

Comment: I did not delete any edges manually and if I did so, I would expect the database to make it possible for me to clean up the "broken graph".

Comment: which OrientDB version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem still present? If you try with recent version (from 2.2.x) there are 2 useful commands:

[CHECK DATABASE](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Console-Command-Check-Database.html) (Checks the integrity of a database. In the case the database contains graphs, their consistency is checked)

[REPAIR DATABASE](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Console-Command-Repair-Database.html) (to repair the DB)